# Decrypted radius access-request packet has appended characters to password

Tags: authentication, wireshark, radius, nps

I am configuring radius for various pieces of equipment on my network.  A certain subset of equipment is getting access-reject packets even though I have everything set up correctly from what I can see.  The only thing I can see different is in the access-request packet in wireshark, the deycrpted password has random characters appended to it.  No other gear does this.  I am wondering why this is happening.
[image]